# Принцип работы открытого и закрытого ключа. Как сделать?

Tags: android, шифрование, aes

Есть задача - передавать зашифрованные данные от сервера - клиенту и наоборот. Но есть проблема, чтобы клиент или сервер смог сообщение расшифровать нужно также передавать ключ, который могут перехватить.

Мы нашли решение в использовании открытого ключа шифрования, но для этого нужно связать открыты и закрытый ключ при этом не передавая никак закрытый.

Как это вообще сделать? Чтобы открытым - шифровать, а закрытым зашифровывать при этом, чтобы было безопасно.

В данном случае мы передаем строку с Json на андройд клиент и наоборот такую же строку. Генерация закрытого ключа должны бать либо на сервере, либо на клиенте, но как связать открытый и закрытый не понятно.

Comment: А почему бы вам не использовать готовый HTTPS (или TLS), которые неплохо защищены от перехвата траффика?

Comment: То есть передача закрытого ключа по https протоколу, и все?

Comment: Сам протокол осуществляет установку защищенного соединения, данные, передаваемые после установки защищенного соединения хорошо защищены от перехвата.

Comment: Есть тогда вообще смысл в шифровании сообщений, если нельзя перехватить?

Comment: Вам решать. Если вы сделаете еще и надежную защиту от MItM, то без отладки приложения получить данные будет проблематично.

Comment: Так эту же атаку нельзя провести через https, только через http, разве нет?

Comment: Можно, для http человек посередине и не нужен, достаточно перехвата траффика.

Comment: Можете показать некоторые ресурсы, которые помогут решить мне эту проблему?

Comment: Гугл. Запросы "https mitm" и "certificate pinning"

Comment: Надо сперва понять для каких целей нужно шифрование. 
Если защита от недоверенной сети, то https достаточно. Если от юзера хотите что-то спрятать, то на эмуляторе и https можно логировать. 
И кастомную логику шифрования реверсить, ведь ключ то будет зашит в приложении.
Так что пусть все "важное" происходит на сервере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В криптографии есть хорошее правило, не стоит пытаться изобрести что-то свое, когда уже есть готовы схемы и алгоритмы, которые находятся под строжайшим взглядом лучших криптоаналитиков. В случае, если вы попытаетесь изобрести свою схему, которая интуитивно выглядит безопасной, на практике она может оказаться менее безопасной, чем известные схемы.

Можно привести хороший пример. В протоколе SSL/TLS использовалась схема MAC-then-encrypt, которая интуитивно кажется более надежной, чем Encrypt-then-MAC. В первом случае шифруется и сообщение и его код аутентификации. Во втором случае, шифруется только сообщение, а код аутентификации передается в открытом виде. Но недавние исследования показали, что Encrypt-then-MAC более безопасен.

По вашему вопросу, вам стоит использовать готовый протокол - TLS. Если у вас есть веб сервер, тогда HTTPS (что по сути является тем же TLS). В TLS реализовано все, что вам нужно, и даже больше.